# DRAG AND DROP OF A VIEW : view returning to original position even after dragging to new position

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-relativelayout

I want to add drag and drop functionality to a textview in my testing app
The main layout contains a relativelayout(RL1)  , which inturn contains another relativelayout(RL2) 
now the RL2  contains a textview which can  able to be dragged and dropped anywhere

But when i perform drag on the textview its getting dragged but went i drop it it returns  back to its originsl position
**please help me**

**my mainactivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

TextView tv;
LayoutParams lParams;
RelativeLayout layout;
private static final String Tv_TAG =" TV_DRAG";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainTextView1);
    tv.setTag(Tv_TAG);
    tv.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());

    layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id. draggableRelativeLayout );
    layout.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
}


private class MyTouchListener implements OnTouchListener
{

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item((CharSequence) v.getTag());
        String[] mimeTypes ={ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN};
        ClipData dragData = new ClipData(v.getTag().toString(), mimeTypes, item);

        View.DragShadowBuilder shdwbldr = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v);

        v.startDrag(dragData, shdwbldr, v, 0);
        v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        return true;
    }


}

private class MyDragListener implements OnDragListener
{

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event)
    {

        View view = (View) event.getLocalState();

        switch (event.getAction()) { 
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED: 
            lParams =(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)view.getLayoutParams(); 
            break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED: 

                int x_cord = (int) event.getX();
                int y_cord = (int) event.getY();

                break; 
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:

                x_cord = (int) event.getX();
                y_cord = (int) event.getY();
                lParams.leftMargin = x_cord;
                lParams.topMargin = y_cord;

                view.setLayoutParams(lParams);

                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP: 
                    // Dropped, reassign View to ViewGroup 

                    ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent(); 
                    owner.removeView(view);
                    RelativeLayout container = (RelativeLayout) v;
                    container.addView(view);
                    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    break; 
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED: 

                    break;
            default: break;

        }

        return true;
    }
}

}
```

**my layout **

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:background="#AE9C9B"
android:id="@+id/ draggableRelativeLayout ">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@null"
    android:id="@+id/mainRelativeLayout1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="DRAG ME"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/mainTextView1"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Understand the code you are using, and read the `View.Shadow` you are dragging. The view is hidden, and a shadow is being moved. [Read the documentation on the functioning](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html) of what you are using.

Comment: @Bonatti can you please elaborate my mistake

Comment: You don't set the new coordinates to your dragged view.

Comment: @Amy thanks for commenting ,,, then to whom should i set the co8rdinates to

Comment: Like the link described, you can read on what the function you used is doing. Once you do, you can understand the mistake done. About the downvote, is due to the lack of reading/understanding of the problem. When you asked `But when i perform drag on the textview its getting dragged but went i drop it it returns back to its originsl position please help me` it shows that you are not understanding what the drag system is, and must read its documentation on what is happening (since what you described is the expected behavior and not a failure).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to set the new coordinates to your view:

```
case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
    v.setX(event.getX());
    v.setY(event.getY());
    break;
```